# Он сдвигался, по мере роста, по крайней мере, последние триста лет

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить запятые в этом предложении?

> Он сдвигался, по мере роста, по крайней мере, последние триста лет.

Comment: А какие у вас варианты? Почему вы в них сомневаетесь и всё ещё ищете ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Он сдвигался по мере роста, по крайней мере, последние триста лет.

"По крайней мере" is an introductory phrase, "по мере роста" is an adverbial modifier.

Comment: Что, что, простите?

Comment: Если русский - ваш родной язык, то вам сюда. https://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Elena пожалуйста, не дезинформируйте людей - на этом стеке приветствуются все люди, интересующиеся русским языком вне зависимости от того насколько он им родной.

Answer (score 1):

Выделяются только вводные слова «по крайней мере», больше нет причины для запятых.
Два слова «мере» в одном предложении смотрятся плохо.Автору лучше заменить вводные слова, если возможно.